# Additional spaces in angularjs select option

Tags: angularjs, forms, select

I have a question.I have a form with select option:

```
<select name="recName" ng-model="newMessage.recName">
   <option ng-repeat="player in newMessage.gamePlayers">
      {{player.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

When I submit the form and debug js file, the recName variable contain player name with extra spaces. For example, player name is "Liam" and in recName is "________Liam_______" after submit.
(I added _ because spaces were ignored)

Does anyone know what is going on? Thanks.

Comment: can you please put your js code or would be better if you provide a plunker that reproduce the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put your code in one line. Something like that :

```
<select name="recName" ng-model="newMessage.recName">
   <option ng-repeat="player in newMessage.gamePlayers">{{player.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First check if the data newMessage.gamePlayers contains spaces before players name.

If yes then you can use .trim() method to remove leading and trailing spaces.

If No then use value attribute with option.

```
<select name="recName" ng-model="newMessage.recName">
   <option ng-repeat="player in newMessage.gamePlayers" value="{{player.name}}">
      {{player.name}}
   </option>
</select>
```

Comment: newMessage.gamePlayers does not contain spaces. The sluotion was what Nigrimmist wrote. :)